# Scanning sub folder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to search files from sd card so i can delete multiple and duplicate files.``

```
private List<String> searchForFileNameContainingSubstring(String substring)
{
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
    //This is assuming you pass in the substring from input.
    File file = new File(path); //Change this to the directory you want to search in.

    List<String> filesContainingSubstring = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory())
    {
        String[] files = file.list(); //get the files in String format.
        for (String fileName : files)
        {
            if (fileName.contains(substring)) 
                filesContainingSubstring.add(fileName);
        }
    }

    for (String fileName : filesContainingSubstring)
    {
        System.out.println(fileName); //or do other operation 
    }

    return filesContainingSubstring; //return the list of filenames containing substring.
}
```

How can i scan other sub folders from sdcard/ directories

It only shows results from sdcard directories

Comment: You can use recursion for each subdirectory you find. http://avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-recursively-display-all-files-and-directories-in-a-directory.html

Comment: After using recursion it gives me stackoverflow exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Apache Common's** [FileUtils.listFiles](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) method.
You can search recursively throughout a folder by setting the third parameter as true.
Also, you can target specific file extensions by passing in the second argument a String array as seen below. If you want to target any extensions pass null.

**Note:** *the extensions names do not include '.' it's "jpg" and not ".jpg"*

```
    String[] extensions = {"png","jpg"};
    Collection images = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("dirPath"),extensions, true);
    for (Object obj : images){
        File file = (File) obj;
        // your code logic
    }
```

Comment: How can i pass String as a file name in this method, sorry but i am new in android development.

Comment: The first argument of listFiles method is a File object.
instead of "dirPath" type the full path to your folder/directory you want to search in.